# SQL QUERY COUNT THEN ADD

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, addition

I want to write a query to return all records from a table , 
If a specific column `value` is under 100 , then `add  +5` to the Value

Comment: Please Edit your question to be more clear with sample data/expected result etc

Comment: i am using sql server

Answer (score 1):

Its `sum` value by each order u will need. According to your original question `orderamount <100` then add 5

```
    WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT OrderID
        ,OrderDate
        ,Customer
        ,ProductAmount
        ,sum(orderamount) orderamount
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY OrderID
        ,OrderDate
        ,Customer
        ,ProductAmount
    )
SELECT OrderID
    ,OrderDate
    ,Customer
    ,ProductAmount
    ,CASE 
        WHEN orderamount < 100
            THEN orderamount + 5
        ELSE orderamount
        END Orderamount
FROM cte
```

Comment: query to return all records from a table and in the query check to see if the order amount is equal to 100 , add a value of 5  ,and then show the revised amount.

Comment: You mean if order amount = 100 then add +5 or display same order amount ?

Comment: This is the table Orders [OrderID  OrderDate Customer Product  Amount ] 

select all fields , 
count order amount for each costumer ,
if count >100 , 
add those rows +5 , 
show the revised amount .

Comment: can u please add expected output with data sample please

Comment: whatever , its not important